# Can eval be called within a data frame with variables defined in that data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, eval

Consider:

```
quotes<-alist(x, x+1, x+2)
data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval))
```

This does not work because `eval` cannot find `x`. Is there any way to get `eval` to recognize the variables that were defined in the data frame? I know that I could assign the data frame to some variables and then build it up with functions like `transform`, but I'm looking to do all of this within my call to `data.frame`.

For a possible version of the intended outputs, we can use this:

```
quotes<-alist(x, x+1, x+2)
x=c(5, 10, 15)
data.frame(x, lapply(quotes, eval))
```

Comment: Not with dataframe but this is possible with tibbles. `tibble(x=c(5, 10, 15), col = lapply(quotes, eval))`

Comment: You can make `data.frame(x=x <- c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval))` but then there is `x` in global.env.

Comment: Not sure what is acceptable here but this works and uses no global variables: `with(list(x = c(5, 10, 15)), 
  data.frame(x, lapply(quotes, eval, data.frame(x))))`  Also `local({
  x <- c(5, 10, 15);
  data.frame(x, lapply(quotes, eval, data.frame(x)))
})`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Both of those violate the "_the variables that were defined in the data frame_" requirement.

Comment: Is Reduce ok?  `Reduce(function(data, quote) cbind(data, eval(quote, data)), quotes, data.frame(x = c(5, 10, 15)))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That's smart enough that I'd upvote it as an answer, but it's too much against the spirit of the problem for me to accept it.

Comment: We could define a recursive function: `fun <- function(data, quotes) if (length(quotes)) Recall(cbind(data, eval(quotes[[1]], data)), quotes[-1]) else data;
fun(data.frame(x = c(5, 10, 15)), quotes)`

Comment: You can also try `local(data.frame(x=x <- c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval, environment())))` where `x` is only in the local environment, but here eval needs to be told that it looks for x in the local environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you noticed that the simpler call `data.frame(x, y = x)` wouldn't work either ?

`data.frame()` uses standard evaluation so in your case they'll be evaluated in the global environment.

If you name your quotes elements you'll be able to do `tibble(x, !!!quotes)` though, because tibble works differently.

Technically the following might be acceptable to you, we cheat by creating a temp value in the global environment, which we then remove on exit.

(I use `evalq` only to be able to use `on.exit`)

```r
quotes<-alist(x, x+1, x+2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(5, 10, 15) ->> .t.e.m.p., 
  evalq({
    on.exit(rm(.t.e.m.p., envir = .GlobalEnv))
    lapply(quotes, eval, list(x= .t.e.m.p.))
  }))

df
#>    x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#> 1  5            5            6            7
#> 2 10           10           11           12
#> 3 15           15           16           17

ls(all.names = TRUE)
#> [1] "df"     "quotes"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This looks of course horrible, and using `transform`, `within` or `tibble` is probably a wiser choice.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't mind when `x` is created in `.GlobalEnv`, and potentially overwriting it, you can use `<-` inside `data.frame`.

```
quotes<-alist(x, x+1, x+2)

data.frame(x=x <- c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval))
#   x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#1  5            5            6            7
#2 10           10           11           12
#3 15           15           16           17

rm(x)
```

You can call it inside `local` but then `x` is not created in the `.GlobalEnv` and `eval` needs to be told to look in current `environment`.

```
local(data.frame(x=x <- c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval, environment())))
#   x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#1  5            5            6            7
#2 10           10           11           12
#3 15           15           16           17
```

It is also possible to assign the values to a different name but here `eval` needs a `list` with the name `x`. Note that in this case *TMP* would be first created or overwritten and if needed, afterwards removed with `rm` from the `.GlobalEnv`.

```
data.frame(x=TMP <- c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval, list(x=TMP)))
#   x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#1  5            5            6            7
#2 10           10           11           12
#3 15           15           16           17

rm(TMP)
```

Other (but not asked/wanted) possibilities might be using `transform`:

```
transform(data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15)), y=lapply(quotes, eval, environment()))
#   x y.c.5..10..15. y.c.6..11..16. y.c.7..12..17.
#1  5              5              6              7
#2 10             10             11             12
#3 15             15             16             17
```

`within`:

```
within(data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15)), y <- lapply(quotes, eval, environment()))
#   x         y
#1  5 5, 10, 15
#2 10 6, 11, 16
#3 15 7, 12, 17
```

or `tibble`:

```
tibble::tibble(x=c(5, 10, 15), y=sapply(quotes, eval, environment()))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#      x y[,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     5     6     7
#2    10    10    11    12
#3    15    15    16    17
```

And finally (for reference) the *intended output* from the question:

```
x <- c(5, 10, 15)
data.frame(x, lapply(quotes, eval))
#   x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#1  5            5            6            7
#2 10           10           11           12
#3 15           15           16           17

rm(x)
```

Comment: Credit where credit's due for the `transform` solution. It's probably the cleanest base R solution. Its only failure is that it takes a great deal of confidence to correctly guess the behaviour of the call to `environment` within a call to `transform`.

Comment: As variables are looked up in the *enclosing environment* and not in the *calling stack* you need to give the `environment` where the variable can be found.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to previous answers using `tibble`, but adding a `data.table` solution for completeness:

```
data.table(x=c(5, 10, 15))[, lapply(quotes, eval, envir=environment())]
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  5  6  7
# 2: 10 11 12
# 3: 15 16 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging `data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15), lapply(quotes, eval))` leads to:

```
x <- list(...)
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found
```

This is due to evaluation of second argument:

```
lapply(quotes, eval)
#Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found
```

A workaround seems here difficult to find without previously defining `x` in the `environment`.

`tibble` allows to use previous variables during definition of further variables, as it relies on non standard evaluation with `quos(...)` instead of `list(...)` to process arguments :

```
function (..., .rows = NULL, .name_repair = c("check_unique", 
  "unique", "universal", "minimal")) 
{
  xs <- quos(...)
  is.null <- map_lgl(xs, quo_is_null)
  tibble_quos(xs[!is.null], .rows, .name_repair)
}
```

With `tibble`:

```
tibble::tibble(x=c(1,2,3), result= sapply(quotes,function(quo) eval(quo)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x result[,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1          1     2     3
2     2          2     3     4
3     3          3     4     5
```

This is however not yet the expected result because `quotes` need to be processed row wise with `x`, for example with `mapply`:

```
tibble::tibble(x=c(1,2,3), result = mapply(function(quo,x) eval(quo),quotes,x))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x result
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      1
2     2      3
3     3      5
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, I think the best solution is to use `tibble()` instead of `data.frame()`. However, if you want to avoid the `tibble` dependency, the best solution would be, I think, to create a custom function `my_frame()` which implements the functionality you need. This can be fairly simple if you're only ever going to be 'defining' values in the first column:

```
my_frame <- function(x, quotes) {
  data.frame(x, lapply(quotes, eval, environment()))
}

my_frame(c(5, 10, 15), quotes)
#>    x c.5..10..15. c.6..11..16. c.7..12..17.
#> 1  5            5            6            7
#> 2 10           10           11           12
#> 3 15           15           16           17
```